# How to solve the upCast error in Zero C Ice compilation? - Gcc - 4.7 compile with clang

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, ice

I have to build Murmur (server of the Mumble VOIP client). Murmur and Mumble use ZeroC Ice 3.4 in its framework. I tried making Murmur and got stuck in a compilation error.

The error is as follows:

```
>/usr/include/Ice/Handle.h: In instantiation of ‘IceInternal::Handle<T>::Handle(T*) [with T = Ice::Communicator]’:
/usr/include/Ice/OutgoingAsync.h:49:16:   required from here
/usr/include/Ice/Handle.h:66:13: error: ‘upCast’ was not declared in this scope, 
and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
```

I tried Googling several times and was stuck with just two links. None of them is solving my problem. I have found a way to implement my requirement in Murmur and Mumble, but this bug is making me go mad.

I hope at least one person have encountered this and solved. I really need a solution for building Murmur.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the almigthy power of google, i found the solution to your problem quite easy.

searching like [this](https://www.google.de/search?q=ZeroC%20%22%E2%80%98upCast%E2%80%99%20was%20not%20declared%20in%20this%20scope%22&aq=f&oq=ZeroC%20%22%E2%80%98upCast%E2%80%99%20was%20not%20declared%20in%20this%20scope%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.5069j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

would yield the outstanding zeroC bug [here](http://www.zeroc.com/forums/bug-reports/4965-slice2cpp-output-does-not-compile-standards-conformant-compiler.html)

Which in turn would link to the [patch 'grembo' (and maybe others) wrote for gcc 4.7 and clang](http://www.zeroc.com/forums/patches/5647-patch-compiling-ice-clang-gcc4-7-a.html)

Yo might need to work on your search engine kung fu. :)